# How does Doctrine generate:entities create getters and setter in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have class User likr this

```
class user implements UserInterface {

protected id ,
protected username;
```

Then i have

```
class student extends user {


protected id ,
protected rollno;
```

Now when i run this

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities myBundle
```

Then propery username gets inserted in class student.

I want to know that is this ok or its error. Because then whats the use of extending from base class if my lass is going to be populated with all stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that's probably not an error, although I agree it can be annoying.

To see how exactly are they generated you can look into the [command class](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php).

Comment: But what purpose they solve. I have removed the all from my class and its working fine. Are those attributes needed there ??

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an error.
Symfony threats all classes as entities and if you're "mapping" them with doctrine you'll create the corrisponding tables onto database.
Now inheritance have to be taken into account: every "field" (property) into parent classe, will be extended or inherited by child.
So is perfectly clear that the corresponding parent field will be created into database.

To me the best way for solve this is to create a parent class and to migrate all commons (fields,methods and so on...) into it.
Then, you'll extend that new parent calss into `user` with specific fields (in that case `username`) aswell into `student` with student's specific fields.

Comment: no no creating database attributes and fields is ok but why it adds attributes in class.php file and make it messy

Comment: @user54418 what do you mean with "inserted" ?

Comment: I mean it gets added in class.php file like we write that propery  `private username` with keyboard

Comment: @Zombie15 : if you open the class.php file, you find them wrote into? Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes u r right. i want to keep those files as short as possible

Comment: @Zombie15 : ok, now i get it. And as i'm new to symfony2 (and symfony in general) i can't help you. Sorry.